# how to add a whiteboard in react application?

Tags: reactjs, whiteboard

I need to add a whiteboard feature in react application. Please tell me any easy way to add a whiteboard in react app. I cannot use canvas to create one from scratch, because less time, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options for you:

https://github.com/mikhail-angelov/react-whiteboard

https://github.com/ohtomi/react-whiteboard

Comment: If you see a question which you think can be answered by linking or naming a tool or lib, then please flag it as off-topic instead of answering.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

It is simple to use indeed.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sketch-whiteboard

Comment: If you see a question which you think can be answered by linking or naming a tool or lib, then please flag it as off-topic instead of answering.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33453338)